# Pyinstaller not creating executable

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, pycharm, pyinstaller

I have been working on an script in tkinter and the EXE fails to create in the dist folder

I have ran this multiple ways the first is `pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w myscript.py`.

It creates all the files and folders but in the dist folder there is no exe file. I then ran it as `pyinstaller.exe myscript.py` where I was able to get it to work however my buttons would quit working. I have included the output below. Ideally I want to use the first option. If you would like to see my code I can post that as well. I'm new to Python and tkinter.

Note: I copied the pyinstaller.exe to the folder where my script it located.

```
C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass>pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w pass.py

199 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6    
200 INFO: Python: 3.7.7
201 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
206 INFO: wrote C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass\pass.spec
210 INFO: UPX is not available.
217 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\test\\PycharmProjects\\pass',
'C:\\Users\\test\\PycharmProjects\\pass']

217 INFO: checking Analysis
220 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
220 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
232 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
244 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3024 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
3032 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib'

4497 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4693 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4700 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable required by c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe

5068 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass\pass.py
5220 INFO: Processing module hooks...
5220 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
5231 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
5450 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
5453 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
5458 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
5750 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
6236 INFO: checking Tree
6236 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
6237 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
6367 INFO: checking Tree
6368 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
6369 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
6417 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
6417 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
6421 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
6434 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
7284 INFO: Looking for eggs
7285 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
7286 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]

7290 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass\build\pass\warn-pass.txt
7340 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass\build\pass\xref-pass.html
7397 INFO: checking PYZ
7398 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
7398 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass\build\pass\PYZ-00.pyz
8029 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass\build\pass\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
8051 INFO: checking PKG
8051 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
8052 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
10983 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
11026 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\runw.exe
11027 INFO: checking EXE
11028 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
11028 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
11035 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\pass\dist\pass.exe
11048 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: try `pyinstaller --onefile -w myscript.py`

Comment: If I had to guess, copying pyinstaller's exe is creating the issue, you should be able to run pyinstaller from command line if it's installed properly, so I'd almost guess that the exe is being made, but is in the `%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts` folder.

Comment: I was able to get this created. I uninstalled 3.7 and all folders related to the 3.7. Went in and removed the path in windows system variables. Then installed 3.8. uninstalled pyinstaller and reinstalled it it still would not run I copied the pyinstalled to my project folder again and run it. I now have the EXE in the dist folder and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not really posting this as an answer, but this little script has made my life easier.

No need to copy pyinstaller's exe, just run the script and select your main python file to make the exe, it makes the build and dist folders where the script was ran.

```
import sys, os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

print(
    """
=======================================
Create a .exe file from a Python Script
=======================================

Select the Python script you want to create the .exe from:

""")

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "./", title = "Select file", filetypes = ((".py files","*.py"),
                                                                                         (".pyw files","*.pyw"),
                                                                                         (".spec","*.spec")))

if file == "." or file == None:
    sys.exit()

if file.endswith('.pyw'):
    #NORMAL
    cmd = ('pyinstaller.exe --windowed --onefile ' + '"' + file + '"')
    os.system(cmd)

elif file.endswith('.py'):   
    #NORMAL
    cmd = ('pyinstaller.exe --onefile ' + '"' + file + '"')
    os.system(cmd)

elif file.endswith('.spec'):
    cmd = ('pyinstaller.exe ' + '"' + file + '"')
    os.system(cmd)

os.system('pause')
```